# Using redisson how to check if a given key is present in redis

Tags: redis, redisson

I have a set of keys and i want to check if any of those are present in my redis db. How can i do so using redisson library ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RedissonKeys.countExists(String... name) can help you to determine if the key exists, without knowing the type of it beforehand.

I think this what you need.

Comment: so i'll have to get all the keys before making this call?

Comment: You can check them one by one, if you like, by just using one key and check if the return value is 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **isExists** function to check whether the key is present in redis or not.

Here is the ref link: [Redis-commands-mapping-with-redisson](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/11.-Redis-commands-mapping)